# How do I automatically fill in a column when a different People column is selected?

Tags: 2010, list, people-picker

I would like to display both the Name and Department fields from a Person.  So I can select two People columns and have one display Name and one display Department, but I'd like to autofill the Department column with the same person that was chosen for the Name column.  How can I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have infopath by chance?

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

I typically do it behind the scenes with a workflow to update that column to the value specified in the form. This means the deparment field doesn't have to be on the form itself, making it shorter.

Other options include code on the Newform page.

Comment: I've tried looking at the workflows I have available, but none of them seem to fit the bill.  What workflow template would you use?  Perhaps I don't have the correct one available. Thanks.

Comment: I just use update item actions and set the person field 2 to person field 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of JavaScript utilizing jQuery for Newform page:

```
var $pickers = $('div[title^=People]');
$pickers.eq(0).blur(function(){
  $pickers.eq(1).html($(this).html());
});
```