# How do I automatically generate a field in a list?

Tags: workflow

So what I want to do is automatically generate Field 2 in List 2 , depending on what value Field 1 has in List 1. Field 1 and Field 2 does not necessarily have to have the same value.

This means that when a person adds an item to List 2 this will happen:

List 1 Has these values:

Field 1 : A
Field 2 : B

The person adds an new item in List 2:

In Field 1, the value A is chosen.
The person then adds the item to the list. Field 2 is automatically generated (depending on values from List 1) and is therefore not included in the form.
When the person looks at the added items in List 2, these values will be shown:

Field 1 : A
Field 2 : B (Automatically generated)

I have already begun making this workflow but have not succeeded. I am thinking of using the Set [Field] to [Value] in Sharepoint Designer.

I hope I didn't make this task too confusing. It is actually a quite simple job to do but I have only just started using this program.

Thank you for your help.

/Pontus

Edit #1: This might give you an slight idea of what I want to create: [How do I automatically fill in a column when a different People column is selected?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45423/how-do-i-automatically-fill-in-a-column-when-a-different-people-column-is-select)

Comment: The only thing that is confusing about your post is: How are you determining which element from list 1 to copy the field value over to list 2?  Is list 1 only a reference for list 2, where nothing is ever added, only searched by list 2 to fill in the rest?

Comment: But what I don't understand is, how do you know which element to reference from list1 when you create a new element in list2?  Is field A like an ID field or something unique to each item that, when parsing through list1, list2 can see the element it shares, and fill in the rest of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, from the comments, it makes perfect sense.  This is a pretty easy problem to overcome.  You are correct in that you need to use "Feld im aktuellen Element Festlegen" to create your new element.  When including the action for list2, set the field in the action to field2.  For the value to put into it, instead of putting in a custom value, use a lookup (It's the fx symbol when you click on the value).  In the lookup options, define your list to lookup as list1, and the value you want from field2.

It will then ask you from which element you want the value of field2.  The first option should be the name of the first field (field1) in list1 that holds the color value.  The next textfield will require another lookup (another click of that fx symbol).  Click that button, and it will bring up the final box.  The first option should be set to "Current Element".  The second option should be set to the first field in list2 (the only field you have a value for in list2, which is the color).

So, to break it down into simple terms.  The value you want is from field2 in list1.  Sharepoint then asks you "How do you know what element holds the value you want?"  So you say "I want the value where the color value in list1 equals the color value from my current element".

I know this may be confusing to follow, and if necessary, I will try to clear it up as best I can.

**EDIT:** Sorry, the action is called "Set field in current element."  I've been working with the German version, so that name came to my head first, haha.

Comment: Yeah!  That's what I meant, and I still got it wrong, haha.

Comment: Almost right, except for one thing.  Field from source should be Field 2, not Field 1 (Field from source: Field 2).  Then it should be Field: Field1 (List 1).

Comment: Is it not working?  The last lookup should be correct with the way I said to change it in my comment.

Comment: Oh, yeah, this lookup works.  The workflow isn't causing redundancies with the lookups.  When you break the entire thing into words, the action is stated thusly: "Set Field2 of List2 to Field2 of List1, where the Field1 values of both lists match."  So this action takes the color value from List2, looks through List1 for the same color, and then sets the Field2 you want to fill in with the Field2 value of the element you just looked up.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of a discussion, and I was going to edit my message.  Yeah, I didn'T realize it is an edit column.  Not sure about that, never used one.  Let me check up on it.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use a lookup column to do this.  If you want to add this kind of functionality to it, it is best if you use the Set field to value on two regular columns.

Comment: All right. It works. But not as intended. You see, before this workflow, you could pick any number with any colour you wanted. Now I want people to select a colour and thats it. When you press submit, this colour will be put together with a number (depending on the connection in List 1). This does work now, but only when you select a number aswell. So lets say I pick the colour green and the number 2 aswell.

Comment: In List 1, The colour green is connected with the number 1, not 2. So that item will generate the correct number, BESIDES the number one. I do not want to include the selection of numbers. But when I remove that option, the colours are put into a seperate category in List 2 and the workflow does not generate Field 2. So now you are left out with either having two numbers connected to one colour, where one number is correct, OR no numbers at all. I obviously want the option 3, where this works as intented. I really appreciate your help and I feel like we are so close to making this work.

Comment: I guess this occurs since the items are divided into categories in List 2, depending on what number that is submitted in the form. But that submitted number can be antyhing, thus, not following the connection between colours and numbers from List 1. Can you help me fix this problem? I want the generated numbers from the workflow to be the categories. I also want to hide Field 1 (= Number) completely from the form - without causing problems with the workflow.

Comment: I just realized that it is the number (look up) that determine what category it is put in, not the number copy. Can't I just overwrite this field so it will be put into the correct category? So instead of Set [Field 2 Copy (List 2)] it will be Set [Field 2 (list 2]

Comment: Hmmm.. I do not know why but the workflow does not even want to initiate the copy of the look up-colours-field. Thus, making it impossible for the next step to initiate since it uses the colours copy field.

Comment: Please clean up this comments thread and if possible move this discussion to chat (might be a problem with to low rep though!)